# Proper disposing of class implementing IDisposable

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable

Which one of the below 2 code pieces is not calling dispose and therefore is bad practice:

```
...
using(SomeIDisposable p = new SomeIDisposable())
{
  return p.GetSomething(...);
}
...
```

or

```
...
return new SomeIDisposable().GetSomething(...);    
...
```

?

Comment: Neither, the 2nd one can never forget to dispose anything since it will never run.  Dumb question.

Comment: What do you mean? It will run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Number two does not call dispose.